# golang http template variable not working

Tags: html, go

I am trying to use http templates in Go to render all the files in a specific folder on the webpage in a list. Every file or folder should also link to it's respective path. I've achieved reading all the items in a folder and saving them to these structs

```
type Item struct {
    Name     string      
    IsFolder bool        
    Info     os.FileInfo 
}

// Items contains a slice of all items in a folder
type Items struct {
    Parent string 
    Items  []Item 
}
```

This is then passed on to a template.ExecuteTemplate function. The template in question looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
    <p>Files in {{.Parent}}</p>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="ftp?f={{ .Parent }}">{{.Parent}}</a></li>
        {{range .Items}} {{if .IsFolder}}
        <li><a href="ftp?f={{ .Parent }}/{{ .Name }}">{{ .Name }}</a></li>
        {{else}}
        <li><a href="ftp?f={{ .Parent }}/{{ .Name }}">{{.Name}}</a></li>
        {{end}} {{end}}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem however, is that when loading the page, the only thing that is returned is the beginning up until

```
<li><a href="ftp?f={{ .Parent }}/{{ .Name }}">{{ .Name }}</a></li>
```

And it stops right after the ?f=
Now, I've tested it before with only {{ .Name }} and that worked absolutely fine, except of course, the link doesn't go anywhere. Rendering {{ .Parent }} in the list place above that one works absolutely fine. 
It also doesn't work if I simply remove the /, that produces exactly the same problem.

Of course my question is Why this happens and how I would go about fixing it.

Ps. you might notice a small security vulnerability, that if you put ../ in the ftp?f= field, you go up the filetree. Yes I know about this, and I will try and fix that. If you have a suggestion on how to fix that, you can also tell me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `{{range .Items}}` until the matching `{{end}}`, the template runs with the context set to the loop variable, i.e. an `Item`. An `Item` does not have parent. You can reach the global context using $: use `{{$.Parent}}` instead.

Comment: Oh right, of course. Thank you so much. Can't believe that has been holding me back for a solid hour.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop, `.` is the current `Item`, and since there is no `Item.Parent` field, there is no `.Parent` in the loop.